# codes inside script loading jquery do not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do you know why my alert does not run unless I remove JQuery `src`?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">

alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');

var alist = [
    ['27',false,'namea','aaa'],
    ['28',false,'nameb','bbb'],
    ['29',false,'namec','ccc'],  
];

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
```

Should be changed to:

```
<script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 different script tags: one for the jquery reference and the other for you js code.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');

var alist = [
    ['27',false,'namea','aaa'],
    ['28',false,'nameb','bbb'],
    ['29',false,'namec','ccc'],

];

</script>
```

Comment: Make sure you put the attribute `type="text/javascript"` on each of the script tags.

Comment: @redolent: while required to validate against HTML 4.01, it make no difference from functional point of view as browsers use it as default. http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html

Answer (score 4):

[`<script>` tags cannot contain a `src` as well as content.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) Pick one or the other; do not pick both.

Comment: so how to load jquery like [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_append) ????

Answer (score 0):

To have jquery and your own javascript stuff you can do this (you need two separate tags, one for jquery, and the other for your own stuff):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
alert('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');

var alist = [
    ['27',false,'namea','aaa'],
    ['28',false,'nameb','bbb'],
    ['29',false,'namec','ccc'],

];

</script>
```